# Celery schedule doesn't trigger the tasks, no error reported

Tags: django, celery

I'm using Django with celery:

In celery.py I have:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send_notes_email': {
        'task': 'send_notes_email_async',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=3), 
    },
}
```

The task is set:

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='send_notes_email_async', max_retries=3)
def send_notes_email_async():
    print('a')
    send_notes_email()
```

Celery is working, recognize the tasks, but doesn't trigger after 3 minutes.
Also no errors.
Redis reports keys
Celery tasks are working without schedule

```
 -------------- celery@WIN-U5VDSO5V1CK v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         PH:0x3d2d128
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
[tasks]
  . send_notes_email_async
```

Answer (score 0):

Your beat schedule configuration is wrong, `minute=3` in cronjob means that execute the task at minute 3 (01:03, 02:03, 03:03, 04:03...).

This is what you want, which executes the task every 3 minutes:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send_notes_email': {
        'task': 'send_notes_email_async',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=*/3), 
    },
}
```